# How to find an element by an attribute getting referenced?

Tags: xpath, reference

I have a quick question about passing an XPath expression as a value for an attribute.
So I have the following document:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<personnel>
<person id="EMP01" >
  <name><family>Lee</family><given>Ho</given></name>
  <email>lee.ho@foo.com</email>
  <salary>100000</salary>
  <links>
    <subordinate>EMP02</subordinate>
    <subordinate>EMP03</subordinate>
  </links>
</person>

<person id="EMP02">
  <name><family>Chan</family><given>Tai Man</given></name>
  <email>chan.tai.man@foo.com</email>
  <salary>20000</salary>
  <links>
    <manager>EMP01</manager>
    <subordinate>EMP04</subordinate>
    <subordinate>EMP05</subordinate>
  </links>
</person>

<person id="EMP03">
  <name><family>Cheung</family><given>Siu Fan</given></name>
  <email>cheung.siu.fan@foo.com</email>
  <salary>20200</salary>
  <links>
    <manager>EMP01</manager>
    <subordinate>EMP07</subordinate>
  </links>
</person>

<person id="EMP04">
  <name><family>Ng</family><given>Ho</given></name>
  <email>ng.ho@foo.com</email>
  <salary>11000</salary>
  <links>
    <manager>EMP02</manager>
  </links>
</person>

<person id="EMP05">
  <name><family>Chow</family><given>Sing Sing</given></name>
  <email>chow.sing.sing@foo.com</email>
  <salary>20050</salary>
  <links>
    <manager>EMP02</manager>
    <subordinate>EMP06</subordinate>
  </links>
</person>

<person id="EMP06">
  <name><family>Law</family><given>Lai</given></name>
  <email>law.lai@foo.com</email>
  <salary>5050</salary>
  <links>
    <manager>EMP05</manager>
  </links>
</person>

<person id="EMP07">
  <name><family>Chan</family><given>Siu Ming</given></name>
  <email>chan.siu.ming@foo.com</email>
  <salary>5000</salary>
  <links>
    <manager>EMP03</manager>
  </links>
</person>
```

And I need an XPath expression to get the person-node of the manager of family with the name Law, so in this case, Mr. Chow. But how can I get this in XPath without explicitly using the name Chow?

My try was:

```
personnel/person[@id="personnel/person/name/family='Law'"]
```

But it doesn't really work... can I pass an XPath as a value for an attribute like this, or how do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use quotes if you want a string to be read as XPath expression instead of literal string. Try something like this :

```
/personnel/person[@id=/personnel/person[name/family='Law']/links/manager]/name/family
```

**<kbd>[`xpathtester demo`](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/6b2fed7e369c331c4a66923c61f80ae0)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
<family>Chow</family>
```

Comment: You can append `/text()`, if you are just interested in the content.

Comment: Ah.... ok, I thought values of attributes always have to be put in quotes^^ Cool, thanks a lo!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
personnel/person[name/family = 'Law']
```

This way you get the entire person node as a result.

http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/76e78418ba5de7779394705dba0585f3